# Qual o erro de sintaxe desse join?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, microsoft-access

Quando uso esse `join`, aparece que tem um erro de sintaxe "operador faltando", alguém consegue me dizer onde está e por que dá esse erro?

```
SELECT tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.NUMERO_ATIVO_FK,
    tbEquipamento.TIPO_EQUIPAMENTO,
    tbMovimentacao.DATA,
    tbTipo_Movimentacao.TIPO_MOVIMENTACAO,
    tbTecnico.NOME_TECNICO,
    tbUsuario.NOME_USUARIO
FROM tbEquipamento_Movimentacao
INNER JOIN tbEquipamento 
    ON tbEquipamento.NUMERO_ATIVO = tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.NUMERO_ATIVO_FK
INNER JOIN tbMovimentacao INNER JOIN tbTipo_Movimentacao INNER JOIN tbTecnico INNER JOIN tbUsuario
    ON tbUsuario.MATRICULA_USUARIO = tbMovimentacao.MATICULA_USUARIO_FK
    ON tbTecnico.MATRICULA_TECNICO = tbMovimentacao.MATRICULA_TECNICO_FK
    ON tbTipo_Movimentacao.COD_TIPO_MOVIMENTACAO = tbMovimentacao.COD_TIPO_MOVIMENTACAO_FK
    ON tbMovimentacao.COD_MOVIMENTACAO =  tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.COD_MOVIMENTACAO_FK
```

Comment: Tem INNER Join sem a comparação

Comment: Não entendi... Qual ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei um problema igual ao seu [no stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929332/multiple-inner-join-sql-access).

De acordo com a resposta, quando há múltiplos JOINs, o Access exige o uso de parênteses.

[Documentação](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/inner-join-operation-b9e73ab6-884a-403e-9f22-cb502feae36a) do suporte da Microsoft.

Como não tenho MS Access, não tenho como simular a sua query para poder validar a sintaxe.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve sempre usar o `inner join` da seguinte maneira:

```
INNER JOIN tbEquipamento ON tbEquipamento.NUMERO_ATIVO = tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.NUMERO_ATIVO_FK
```

Ou seja, faça o inner/left/right join na tabela e faça a comparação na outra tabela.

Comment: Nunca usei o Left/Right. Como ficaria nesse caso ?

Comment: A devMedia tem um conteúdo bem legal. De uma olhada https://www.devmedia.com.br/clausulas-inner-join-left-join-e-right-join-no-sql-server/18930

Answer (score 0):

O erro é que você agrupou os `join` e depois os `on`.

A estrutura `JOIN tabela ON campo_1 = campo_2` devem **sempre** ser mantida; ou seja, ao *"juntar"* uma tabela, você deverá indicar o campo de ligação antes de *juntar* a próxima, ficando a consulta assim:

```
SELECT tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.NUMERO_ATIVO_FK,
    tbEquipamento.TIPO_EQUIPAMENTO,
    tbMovimentacao.DATA,
    tbTipo_Movimentacao.TIPO_MOVIMENTACAO,
    tbTecnico.NOME_TECNICO,
    tbUsuario.NOME_USUARIO
FROM tbEquipamento_Movimentacao
INNER JOIN tbEquipamento ON tbEquipamento.NUMERO_ATIVO = tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.NUMERO_ATIVO_FK
INNER JOIN tbMovimentacao ON tbMovimentacao.COD_MOVIMENTACAO =  tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.COD_MOVIMENTACAO_FK
INNER JOIN tbTipo_Movimentacao ON tbTipo_Movimentacao.COD_TIPO_MOVIMENTACAO = tbMovimentacao.COD_TIPO_MOVIMENTACAO_FK
INNER JOIN tbTecnico ON tbTecnico.MATRICULA_TECNICO = tbMovimentacao.MATRICULA_TECNICO_FK
INNER JOIN tbUsuario ON tbUsuario.MATRICULA_USUARIO = tbMovimentacao.MATICULA_USUARIO_FK
```

obs: perceba que a ordem dos `on` precisou ser alterada, já que a condição é específica da tabela que está sendo adicionada à consulta. Em outras palavras, ao fazer *join* com a tabela `tbTipo_Movimentacao` você precisa indicar um campo de uma tabela que *"já está na consulta"* como ligação, no caso, `tbMovimentacao`.

Comment: Boa tarde rLinhares, tudo bem ? 
Cara, gostei da sua explicação, você acrescentou algumas coisas que ainda não tinha conhecimento. Porém o código deu um "Erro de sintaxe (operador faltando) na expressão de consulta 'tbEquipamento.NUMERO_ATIVO =  tbEquipamento_Movimentacao [...]"

Comment: não sei se vai ser o caso do _ms-access_, mas tenta jogar o `on` na mesma linha do `join` (sem dar enter). De qualquer forma, vou alterar a resposta..

Comment: Realmente não era isso, continuou o mesmo erro

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido da seguinte maneira:
SELECT tbEquipamento.NUMERO_ATIVO,
    tbEquipamento.TIPO_EQUIPAMENTO,
    tbMovimentacao.DATA,
    tbTipo_Movimentacao.TIPO_MOVIMENTACAO,
    tbTecnico.NOME_TECNICO, tbUsuario.NOME_USUARIO
FROM tbTipo_Movimentacao 
   INNER JOIN (tbUsuario 
   INNER JOIN (tbTecnico 
   INNER JOIN (tbMovimentacao 
   INNER JOIN (tbEquipamento 
   INNER JOIN tbEquipamento_Movimentacao 
      ON tbEquipamento.NUMERO_ATIVO = tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.NUMERO_ATIVO_FK) 
      ON tbMovimentacao.COD_MOVIMENTACAO = tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.COD_MOVIMENTACAO_FK) 
      ON tbTecnico.MATRICULA_TECNICO = tbMovimentacao.MATRICULA_TECNICO_FK)
      ON tbUsuario.MATRICULA_USUARIO = tbMovimentacao.MATICULA_USUARIO_FK) 
      ON tbTipo_Movimentacao.COD_TIPO_MOVIMENTACAO = tbMovimentacao.COD_TIPO_MOVIMENTACAO_FK;